# Locally set up express, mysql application and working fine but how to set it up in AWS ubuntu server the same application

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I have setup api application using `Express js`, Bookshelf ORM, Mysql into my local host, which is windows system. Now this application I want to set it up in `AWS` server.

I have uploaded all the files and trying with command :
`npm start =>` here giving me error

```
import app from 'App' => unexpected identifier.
```

Please need help how to set it up in the live server.

Comment: you can try aws elasticbeanstalk, which provides preconfigured system.

Comment: I used ec2 instance with Ubuntu server, RDS service for mysql. but need to execute express aplication

Comment: from basic Google, it states it is a syntax error if you want to check if is server issue try to run Hello World application and see if it runs.